# Написал на java телеграмм бота, но он падает при обращении к нему второго пользователя

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Такая ошибка вылетает, после того когда второй пользователь начинает писать боту

```
мая 18, 2022 2:37:28 PM org.telegram.telegrambots.logging.BotLogger severe
SEVERE: BOTSESSION
org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Unable to deserialize response
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.updates.GetUpdates.deserializeResponse(GetUpdates.java:122)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$ReaderThread.getUpdatesFromServer(DefaultBotSession.java:256)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$ReaderThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:187)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value (5145830341) out of range of int
 at [Source: {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":901099310,
"message":{"message_id":33,"from":{"id":5145830341,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"\u041b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0432\u044c","last_name":"\u041f\u0430\u0432\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":5145830341,"first_name":"\u041b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0432\u044c","last_name":"\u041f\u0430\u0432\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430","type":"private"},"date":1652873846,"text":"/start","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"type":"bot_command"}]}}]}; line: 2, column: 51]
 at [Source: {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":901099310,
"message":{"message_id":33,"from":{"id":5145830341,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"\u041b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0432\u044c","last_name":"\u041f\u0430\u0432\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":5145830341,"first_name":"\u041b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0432\u044c","last_name":"\u041f\u0430\u0432\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430","type":"private"},"date":1652873846,"text":"/start","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"type":"bot_command"}]}}]}; line: 2, column: 41] (through reference chain: org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.ApiResponse["result"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update["message"]->org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Message["from"]->org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.User["id"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:388)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:348)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1607)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:278)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:108)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:108)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:259)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:108)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2861)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.updates.GetUpdates.deserializeResponse(GetUpdates.java:114)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Numeric value (5145830341) out of range of int
 at [Source: {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":901099310,
"message":{"message_id":33,"from":{"id":5145830341,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"\u041b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0432\u044c","last_name":"\u041f\u0430\u0432\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":5145830341,"first_name":"\u041b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0432\u044c","last_name":"\u041f\u0430\u0432\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430","type":"private"},"date":1652873846,"text":"/start","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"type":"bot_command"}]}}]}; line: 2, column: 51]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.convertNumberToInt(ParserBase.java:928)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._parseIntValue(ParserBase.java:866)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.getIntValue(ParserBase.java:694)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:306)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:286)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:108)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
    ... 21 more


Process finished with exit code 130
```

Comment: Добавьте ошибку текстом вместо скриншота. И код класса в который у вас десериализуется json. Теоретически может помочь замена типа для id с int на long, но это не точно.

Comment: Здравствуй Insolor.  Добавил текст.

Comment: Главное это добавьте код класса, как написал insolor выше